# Implement Angular js website sidebar in angular js

Tags: angularjs, lodash

I am implementing angular js sidebar from https://material.angularjs.org
as said [Create a menu like in AngularJs Material website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28389671/create-a-menu-like-in-angularjs-material-website#comment58278906_28389671)
The "Component" is found in [componentsData.js](https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/docs/config/processors/componentsData.js) process 
But  file requires Lodash module. Is it possible to use lodash in angular js? Or the Material website is made by angular not angular JS ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Short answer is yes it is possible. Using lodash poses no conflicts

Comment: @charlietfl Is there a step by step tutorial online? I have added lodash, the "Component" module asks for chai.js. but when I add chai.js I get conflict 
`Module name "assertion-error" has not been loaded yet for context:`

Comment: Questions asking for a tutorial are off-topic for Stackoverflow. When asking a question, people will be better able to provide help if you provide code that they can easily understand and use to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `bower` you may checkout lodash directly using command

```
bower install lodash
```

Ref: https://libraries.io/bower/lodash